# Trouble starting gazebo_experimental - Failed to load plugin [gazeboGuiDisplayImage]

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello.  I'd like to contribute to gazebo_experimental, and have successfully built everything from source on a clean Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I followed this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_dependencies_from_source) to build all dependencies from source (in debug mode).  Then I followed instructions [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_experimental/overview) to attempt to build (in debug mode) and run.  The build was clean, and all tests pass.  But when I run `gazebo -v 4`, I get the following errors:

```
[GUI] [Msg] Init app
[GUI] [Err] [PluginLoader.cc:89] Library[] does not exist!
[GUI] [Err] [Iface.cc:244] Failed to load plugin [gazeboGuiDisplayImage]
[GUI] [Err] [PluginLoader.cc:89] Library[] does not exist!
[GUI] [Err] [Iface.cc:244] Failed to load plugin [gazeboGuiDiagnostics]
[GUI] [Msg] Create main window
[GUI] [Msg] Run main window
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QMenuBar::aboutToShow()
```

My ENV variables are set as follows:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/dev/gazebo/gazebo_experimental/build$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/local/lib
vagrant@vagrant:~/dev/gazebo/gazebo_experimental/build$ echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH 
/usr/local/lib:examples/dummy_demo/systems/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16468/trouble-starting-gazebo_experimental---failed-to-load-plugin-%5Bgazeboguidisplayimage%5D/) by [jakelevirne](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3378/jakelevirne/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I answered my own question.  I was missing the IGN_GUI_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable.  I set it to the full path of my gazebo_experimental build `src/gui` directory and was able to run the dummy_demo.

---

Originally posted by [jakelevirne](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3378/jakelevirne/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1